# Executing php as sudo inside crontab

Tags: php, iptables, cron, sudo

I've wrote a PHP-Script, and the execution requires sudo permission, because it executes some other system related stuff. So i've added this into the `crontab -e` but i can't see, that my script is running correctly.

Command:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /srv/www/php/script.php && date > /srv/www/php/mylog.log
```

The only output is the date. No response from my script. It is executable (chmod a+x) and if i use the same command in the terminal as root, everything is okay. So it's up to `crontab -e`?

Also i made sure, that my cronjob is running (/var/log/syslog):

```
Oct 23 16:40:01 $MYMACHINE CRON[13797]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /srv/www/php/script.php && date > /srv/www/php/mylog.log)
```

And this every 5 mins. Also my "mylog.log" always got the latest timestamp, so i guess, there's might be a problem with the script inside.

EDIT:
I've created another test script to check, if the scripts getting executed or not. But the script was executed, so it's a problem inside the script.

I am trying to add dynamically IPs to an iptables chain:

```
#!/bin/bash
value=`cat whitelist.txt`
#echo "$value"

for i in $(echo $value | tr "," "\n")
do
  # process
  /sbin/iptables -I teamspeakCommunication --src $i -j ACCEPT
done
```

May you can see something weird?

Comment: @AD7six please see my edit :)

Comment: Well, I was writing an answer based on the format of your cron line being wrong, but you've since edited your question to be what it *should* look like. Did you have the initial format in your crontab or the one you currently have in the question?

Comment: Yeah, excuse me. I have the edited on inside my Crontab  -e. Also the php error log is empty. But I really doubt, that the problem is not php combined with sudo. I've added the command as root

Comment: Do you expect the output from your script in `mylog.log`?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your /etc/crontab file like this:

`*/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /srv/www/script.php && date > /srv/www/php/mylog.log`

If your script's first line is `#!/usr/bin/php` and execution permission as well, you can call it directly like any other script, like the ones written in bash, perl, etc...

Best regards!

Comment: Pretty nice suggestion! But i transferd my complete logic into a bash script now, and added this into the /etc/crontab - as your line is.But the shell script won't getting executed as well?

Comment: Does it have execution permission? Also, why don't you try to put the redirection into your bash script as well? What does `/var/log/syslog` say now? It **should** work, but since it is not, I suggest you debug it sending the output of each and every command to a text-file...